# Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target class [PostsController] does not exist

Tags: laravel

Can Someone please help me on laravel postcontroller? I am using Laravel 8 but I am seeing below error though my Postcontroller is existing on app>Http>Controllers>PostController.php. Below is my code and I appreciate yoenter image description hereur help in advance.

### Routes

```php
<?php 

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route; 
use App\Http\Controllers\PostsController; 

Route::get('/', function () { 
   return view('welcome'); 
}); 

Auth::routes(); 
Route:: get('/p/create','PostsController@create'); 
Route::get('/profiles/{users}',[App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

### PostController

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 

class PostsController extends Controller { 
      public function create() { 
          return view ('posts/create'); 
      } 
}
```

Comment: sorry let me publish it again

Comment: try to run `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostsController;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| 
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route:: get('/p/create','PostsController@create');

Route::get('/profiles/{users}', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Comment: This is also my postcontroller.php <?php


use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller    
{
    public function create()
{

    return view ('posts/create');
}

}

Comment: Should I run composer dumpautoload on terminal?? sorry Im a newbie here'

Comment: @Veejayguibone the problem looks that you forgot to add the namespace of the controller `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` after that run from your terminal `composer dumpautoload `

Comment: I am still getting an error @Joseph can I share here my file?

Comment: could you try to remove this `PostController` and create another one by running `php artisan make:controller PostController` from your terminal and everything should go fine

Comment: I also tried but same error appear Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [PostsController] does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Insead of :

```
Route:: get('/p/create','PostsController@create');
```

use :

```
Route:: get('/p/create',[PostsController::class , 'create']);
```

You can read more about laravel 8 routes here:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#the-default-route-files